# OpenCV not installing via pip install opencv nor pip install cv2

Tags: python, opencv

I tried to install OpenCV using pip install opencv, but got the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.0.1; however, version 21.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\users\ozark\appdata\local\programs\python\python38- 
32\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Then I tried using pip install cv2, but again got an error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cv2
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cv2
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.0.1; however, version 21.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\users\ozark\appdata\local\programs\python\python38- 
32\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

What am I doing wrong? I read the docs, and it clearly said to use cv2? Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, you actually have to use pip install opencv-python to install OpenCV via pip. You have to use "cv2" when *importing* the module.

Example:

```
import cv2
```

And:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

I hope this helps, and happy coding!

Comment: This actually worked! Thanks so much, when I looked back in the documentation, this was actually what it said, and cv2 is used when importing the module. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, I'm happy to help. Please accept the answer if it is useful.

Comment: Yes, I'm accepting, thank you so much for the help.